# Toad SQLPlus - @Script run serial or parallel

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, toad

I am using Toad and I have following code to run several PL/SQL scripts "in a row" (via Execute SQL via SQLPlus button):

```
DECLARE
  start_date_key    NUMBER(38);
  end_date_key      NUMBER(38);
BEGIN

    start_date_key := 20210501;
    end_date_key := 20210531;
    
    FOR i IN start_date_key .. end_date_key
    LOOP

        @1_script1.sql;
        @2_script2.sql;
        @3_script3.sql;
  
    END LOOP;
END;
```

But from error messages it makes me confused, because it seems to me, that it runs all scripts at once (in parallel, not serial - as I want). Can you correct me, if I am wrong?

How this SQLPlus executor will execute these kind of PL/SQL script?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't have Toad, but SQL\*Plus replaces script names like `@1_script1.sql` in a PL/SQL block with the contents of the script before submitting the block to the database for processing. It will not submit them in parallel. Most likely Toad emulates SQL\*Plus.

Comment: PL/SQL is not a general purpose language and it is not intended to run in parallel (of course, I'm about inter statement parallelism). Moreover, Oracle provides enough tools to make the code explicitly parallel: quite simple [`DBMS_JOB`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_job.htm#ARPLS66567), more complex and flexible [`DBMS_SCHEDULER`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72273) (even with chains and event-based jobs) and [`DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_parallel_ex.htm#ARPLS233) for batching of table operations

Comment: Thank you, I need it to run in serial mode, I was only not sure about execution.